# Call DB Function on Java Entity

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

I've try using @Formula but the result is null in the db. So my question is how we can use some function in the @PrePersist or @Formula?
Does we have another solution for this?

```
@Id
@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;

@Formula(value = "someschema.somefunction(`name`)")
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name; 

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate(){
    this.id = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

1. We can't use `@Formula` for insert data using function, example

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "insert into customer " +
        "(name, description, phone, id) " +
        "VALUES (somefunction.encode_user(:name, 10, 'AES256', 'T', 'C'), " +
        ":description, " +
        ":phone, " +
        ":id)", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
void insertCustomer(
        @Param("id") String id,
        @Param("name") String Name,
        @Param("description") String Description,
        @Param("phone") String Phone
);
```

2. We can only use `@Formula` for query function purposes.